# "appleeventsd" slows down Word + EndNote

Tags: macos, performance

I'm writing my doctoral thesis on a Macbook pro using MS Word 2011 and Endnote X6 (Mac Word and Endnote on the newest version).
Word responses really slowly to any input like typing or scrolling, with a delay of sometimes more than 4 seconds. Super annoying.
My google-research on the problem led to the conclusion that there is no resolution yet. BUT: a workaround is to kill the process "appleeventsd" in Activity Monitor.

And that works super well, killing it lets word respond immediately again, without any delay.

Now my problem: appleeventsd starts again after a couple of minutes, sometimes just 2. This is really annoying because I can't really concentrate on working for a longer period of time as I  always get interrupted by having to kill appleeventsd.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this? What is appleeventsd doing for me? Do I even need it? Could I completely delete it from my system in order to prevent it from starting again? Or can I at least prevent it from restarting after I killed it so I can focus on working without interruptions?

Thank you so much for your help!!

Alek

Comment: It's a [known bug](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/70295) with the Apple Events Daemon in 10.8.2 which affects *lots* of apps, and I doubt you can do anything to fix it besides running `sudo killall -KILL appleeventsd` repeatedly and waiting for Apple to release an update.

Comment: do you know a way to kill it automatically? What is actually annoying is having to do it by myself all the time.

Comment: like a script or so?

Comment: I guess you can use something like [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) (here's a [free frontend](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/7486/cronnix)) or [launchd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) or perhaps even [Automator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automator_%28software%29) to repeatedly run the `killall` command. Apple.SE would be a good place to ask.

Comment: Hey, I was trying cronix but it always crashed unexpectedly.

Comment: So I tried automator, but I kind of don't get how to run a sudo command in automator. I do have to choose "execute a shell script" in automator, right?

Comment: You're welcome, and I encourage you to post the script/workaround below as an answer to your own question. If it needs to be cleaned up, someone is likely to get round to it (eventually). :)

Comment: As @Karen suggested, please post the script you are using as a solution so that others can benefit from it. I am having a similar issue with appleeventsd and would like to try out your solution.

Answer (score 0):

**The origin: a bug in OSX 10.8.2**
This problem is caused by a [bug in Mac OSX 10.8.2](http://mjtsai.com/blog/2012/10/04/aesendmessage-bug-in-mac-os-x-10-8-2/) ([also more info here](http://www.openradar.me/12424662)). It should be solved in 10.8.3, although [the 10.8.3 release info from Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5612) makes no mention about resolving this bug. Some users reported [it to be back in 10.9.0](http://mjtsai.com/blog/2012/10/04/aesendmessage-bug-in-mac-os-x-10-8-2/).

**Current situation**
As the current release (at the time of this post) is [10.9.5](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1760) (released 17 September 2014) is already some subversions past 10.9.0 and I can't find any recent new information about this bug, I think it's safe to assume that the bug currently isn't present anymore.

**The solution**
The best solution would be to update your Mac to the most recent update of OSX.